# Description of the Kameda-Weiner algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, finite-automata, minimization

I'm looking for an explanation of the Kameda-Weiner algorithm.

I found the paper "On the State Minimization of Nondeterministic Finite Automata" which, I assume, contains this, though it's unfortunately behind a paywall, and I'm just a hobbyist.

Can someone explain the algorithm, or point me to another source?

Comment: Here's said CS question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13591/free-description-of-the-kameda-weiner-algorithm

Comment: [You shouldn't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Dukeling I hadn't planned to, and originally chose the CS site. But, then I saw that the CS site's membership and activity is not even a faint glimmer of the activity here, and decided I'd have better luck here, and I was right. Seems to me that there is a bigger problem at hand.

Comment: You do have to wait a bit longer to get an answer on CS, but the average quality of answers tends to be a lot higher. That said, questions obviously still needs to be on topic wherever it's posted and good questions that are on topic for both sites should preferably go on CS specifically because it's a smaller site (and still in Beta). But if you're not willing to (sometimes) wait a day or two, or if you're looking for that one other person in the world that knows what you're talking about, CS is probably not for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13591/free-description-of-the-kameda-weiner-algorithm

Comment: After reading the help center link on off topic posts, I did not find anything remotely suggesting that duplicate questions on other stack exchange sites are off topic. This question is about a software algorithm, which is on topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implemented here: https://github.com/coder0xff/parlex_legacy/blob/132e4a23a599140d22b18ead832626f0c607340f/Automata/NFA.cs#L641

(updated to fix dead link)

Answer (score 2):

Although I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about, I think these two pdf files contain some sort of explanation.

[Link1](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?paperID=22405)

[Link2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5585.pdf)

I just tried to answer it, because I know how frustrating it can be, when you something you really want is behind a paywall! Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Good for you!  I was about to post the exact links as well.

Comment: I found it on the IEEE site for only $19. I just went ahead and bought it. Once I've studied it thoroughly, I may make a wikipedia entry.